# Minecraft TNT Velocity plugin

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm currently working on a PaperMC plugin for my Minecraft server, and I'm looking for a way to increase the knockback effect experienced by TNT entities when they are hit or damaged. By default, when TNT entities are struck, they receive a certain amount of knockback. However, I'd like to amplify this effect so that TNT entities are pushed farther away when they are hit. I've already explored modifying the TNT velocity and other properties, but I'm unsure how to specifically increase the knockback taken by TNT entities.

```
package pl;

import org.bukkit.entity.TNTPrimed;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.ExplosionPrimeEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.util.Vector;

public class pl extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        // Register the event listener
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onTNTIgnite(ExplosionPrimeEvent event) {
        if (event.getEntity() instanceof TNTPrimed) {
            TNTPrimed tnt = (TNTPrimed) event.getEntity();

            // Increase the velocity of the TNT by 75%
            Vector velocity = tnt.getVelocity();
            tnt.setVelocity(velocity.multiply(1.75));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I've tried using but it doesn't seem to be working properly after many tests.

Comment: `ExplosionPrimeEvent` is fired just before the TNT explodes. So setting its velocity will be meaningless as the explosion occurs almost immediately. What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to increase the knockback a tnt gets from another one by 75%, you know like hypixel

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never been on Hypixel, so I don't know. I suggest you edit your question to explain what you want to happen and what does happen.

Comment: ok so I've updated it, can you give me some feedback and tell me if what I wrote is actually clear, thank you.

Comment: That's better; I understand what you want now. As you're using Paper, try using the `TNTPrimeEvent` instead of `ExplosionPrimeEvent`.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working but thank you for trying to help